# merging two queries together via mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to merge two queries together, but I do not know how!

First query:

```
SELECT tablesite.name,
           tablesite.family,
           job_list.job_name,
           tablesite.phone_number
           FROM  tablesite 
           INNER JOIN relation
           on tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
           INNER JOIN job_list
           on relation.job_id=job_list.job_id
```

> I have jobs in this query.

[image: first table]

---

---

---

Second query:

```
SELECT tablesite.name,
       tablesite.family,
       tablesite.phone_number,
       COUNT(action.service_provider_id)
       FROM tablesite
       LEFT JOIN action
       ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
       AND action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment =''
       GROUP BY name, family, phone_number
```

Result of this table is this:

> i have COUNT(action.service_provider_id)  when  COUNT(action.service_provider_id) in second query

[image: result of second table]

after merging these two tables, the result have to like this:

i made this with paint :p :D

[image: final table]

> used tables

tablesite:

[image: tablesite]

action:

[image: action]

relation:

[image: relation]

job_list:

[image]

> sasha tried this:
>   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results of both queries can be combined like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (KEY(name,family,phone_number)) SELECT tablesite.name,
               tablesite.family,
               job_list.job_name,
               tablesite.phone_number
               FROM  tablesite 
               INNER JOIN relation
               on tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
               INNER JOIN job_list
               on relation.job_id=job_list.job_id;    
SELECT ts.name,
           ts.family,
           ts.phone_number,t1.job_name,
           COUNT(action.service_provider_id)
           FROM tablesite ts JOIN t1 USING(name,family,phone_number)
           LEFT JOIN action
           ON ts.id_user=action.service_provider_id
           AND action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment =''
           GROUP BY name, family, job_name, phone_number;
```

It is possible to avoid the use of the temporary table using a sub-query, but it would run into issues if the result set is large due to the lack of join key in the sub-query result.

Comment: this is not true. this way prints second query after first query, no merging

Comment: Sorry - I did not quite get what you wanted on the first read, see my updated solution.

Comment: sasha i have this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'tablesite.name' in 'field list'

Comment: i've added a picture of your code. its not true :( see that end of post

Comment: cant merge two queries in only one? i mean using of join.

Comment: See my edit - I added job_name into the list of group by. You can do it in one query, but it will be significantly slower than in two if the result set is large. MySQL does not do a good job with creating keys for the sub-query result join, so it is better to do it manually with a temporary table.

Comment: you made it bro, many many many thanks. u forgot to edit this line ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id **to** ON ts.id_user=action.service_provider_id